# Topological sorting asm x86

Tags: assembly, x86, topological-sort, emu8086

I'm having big problems with writing an asm x86 code in emu8086 that finds a topological sorting of a graph (with no cicles) given its adjacency matrix, and the number of nodes. I've tried a couple of ideas but nothing has worked...so if any of you guys could give me ANY help (in words or in code) with how to solve this, or how to aproach this problem, it would be great 'cause I don't know what to do...
The data is given like this:

```
JMP main
size db 4
graph db 0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0
ordering db 0 ,0 ,0 ,0
main :
```

I think that the DFS algorithm could be the best to solve this. But again, I sincerely have tried everything and nothing has worked so far...so I will apreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!!! (and sorry for the bad english)

Edit: I wrote this but it doesn't work at all:

```
JMP main
size db 4
graph db 0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0
ordering db 0 ,0 ,0 ,0  
permanente db 0, 0, 0, 0  

main :
MOV CL,1
PUSH CX
LEA BX,graph
PUSH BX
CALL visitar
RET

visitar:
PUSH BP
MOV BP,SP 
MOV BX,[BP+4]
MOV CX,[BP+6]
LEA DI,size
MOV DX,[DI]
MOV SI,0  

for:
CMP SI,DX
JE end_for
CMP [BX+SI],1
JE nodo
JMP next

nodo:
MOV CX,SI
ADD CX,1
PUSH CX
MOV AX,SI
MUL size
LEA BX,graph
ADD BX,AX
PUSH BX
CALL visitar

next:
ADD SI,1
JMP for 


end_for:
LEA DI,permanente
ADD DI,CX 
SUB DI,1
MOV [DI],1

MOV SI,DX
LEA DX,ordering

bajar:
SUB SI,1
CMP [DX+SI],0
JE cambiar 
CMP SI,0
JG bajar 

cambiar:
MOV [DX+SI],CX
CMP SI,0
JE return
JMP revisar

revisar:
LEA AX,permanente
MOV SI,0  
sumar:
CMP [AX+SI],0
JE seguir
ADD SI,1
LEA DI,size
MOV DX,[DI]
CMP SI,DX
JE return
JMP sumar
seguir:
JMP nodo

return:
POP BP
RET 4
```

Comment: Show the algorithm, then show how you translated that to assembly (with comments), show expected and actual results. Also, use a debugger.

Comment: Actually I don't even know what is `size`, `graph` and `ordering`. Is like 4 nodes, and then 4x4 bytes denote connection between nodes? So 3rd node has connection to 4th, which doesn't have any connection? Edges are single-way only? And also I can't recall what is "topological" sort of graph, and what is DFS ... yet I'm quite sure, if you would show example data, expected output, and your algorithm design or source, I would be able to tell if it works or not.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

Comment: I agree with Jester.  If you are going to do something complicated like a topological sort, you'd be smart to code one first in C and debug it.  Then translating to assembler will be a lot easier.   Inquiring minds would like to know, however, if you get a version running in C, why would you want a version in assembler?  What you are doing that requires the presumed value of a high-performance assembly implementation, given that C compilers these days produce very good code?

Comment: @IraBaxter from the emu8086 usage I would say it's clearly educational project, probably some Assembly class. And then doing something as topological sort is valid task, actually the DFS algorithm can be written in asm quite easily and in straightforward way (I bet I would have it in 20-30min done), I would rate it as "after initial examples" difficulty, maybe to be taught even before strings and decimal formatting mess. But the OP doesn't show what is his problem, so no way to help him.

Comment: @Ped7g I edited the code I wrote...it doesnt work and is very hard to understand. I honestly have no clue on finding a better solution to this. If you could show me one way to do this, it would be awesome.

Comment: @gianfrancobordoni: you don't seem to be taking advice.

Comment: @Ped7g Oh, and the graph it's a DAG, size it's of course the number of nodes, and ordering is where the topological order has to be saved.

Comment: What is hard to understand? You have many bugs in that code, but some of them must be visible even if you debug your current version (some are somewhat hidden and by luck can go unnoticed for this input). But if I do get the "idea" of that code, it doesn't feel completely off, it may eventually work if you would fix all issues (although it's written in a bit more complex way I would expect, so it was hard for me to follow the algorithm completely). I may point some bugs to you in answer, but generally it looks you are doing something. It's just not easy. And Assembly is not easy. Debug harder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bugs I caught by reading the source (I don't claim any completeness of the list, there may be more):

```
LEA DI,size
MOV DX,[DI]
```

Size is declared as byte, but you fetch word, so you are actually fetching size + first edge from graph. If the first edge would be 1, the `dx` would be 300 instead of expected 4.

Either extend `size` to word by `dw` declaration, or work with bytes only.

Also you can fetch the size directly from address like `mov dx,[size]`, no need to `lea` it's address.

---

```
CMP [BX+SI],1
```

I don't like this syntax, it's not clear what size is compared. I'm not sure what emu8086 syntax has, try adding `byte` on either side like `BYTE 1`, or `BYTE PTR [bx+si]` like TASM/MASM syntax. I hope one of it would work.

While this may look like "style" preference, if your edges definition would be more complex than 0/1 and use words, it would be bug (as I suspect the default result is byte compare).

---

```
MUL size
```

Check the instruction guide for details. You destroy content of one other register, which would make your `for` to fail.

Also I don't like the syntax, you want the value from memory at `size` address, not the address itself, so adding `[]` around size makes it easier to understand, that you are interested into memory content.

And finally no data size is specified, I missed that one completely. So if the assembler treats this as byte, then the first remark about destroyed register content is invalid, but then it looks like you wanted to do ax*size, which would require word specifier. BTW, you already had size loaded in `dx`, so `mul dx` or `mul dl` would save you memory access.

---

```
CALL visitar
```

Your lack of high-level documentation does catch you here.

When creating assembly functions, always document in comments what are parameters (how to call it), what is the result (if any), and what registers are modified.

Your `visitar` does modify many registers, yet during the `for` loop you somehow expect the `si` to be preserved. It's not. Then later you work with `cx` as original node number, but again, already destroyed during preparation of call parameters. Etc... as it's recursive call, you can be pretty much sure it destroys all registers, which are important to you.

---

You store words into `ordering`, while it's defined as byte array, and offsets are in bytes.

---

```
MOV CL,1
PUSH CX
```

`ch` is uninitialized here (it's probably zero by emu8086, but it's better to initialize everything, as different target platforms may call your "start" in different state.

---

How to improve what you have:

I would do some design work, what are global variables and what are locals. Then you may try to keep globals around, like size doesn't change during whole run, or ordering[next_to_write] pointer is global, etc.

push/pop important registers before calling `visitar` to preserve their values. Or as you work with stack frame anyway because of using stack for function arguments, consider putting local variables into stack (`sub sp,reserved_space` and accessing it by `[bp-x]`). That way you don't need to worry about modified registers, although it will work slower due to memory access.

Make sure you are using correct size of all values. Decide whether number of nodes (`size`) is byte or word, that pretty much decides the rest of variables. Although your `graph` definition is size*size long, so actually you can't have more than ~200 nodes anyway, so going for `byte` size only is OK. But that means to stick with it, ie. `mov [dx+si],cl` to store node number into `ordering`. And when addressing graph, make sure the `mul` works for 16+ size too.

---

Some style notes:

`add/sub r16,1` -> there're also `inc/dec` instructions.

`LEA AX,permanente` - original Intel syntax requires the expression to be like accessing memory, so `LEA AX,[permanente]` looks more like Intel intended it. Although in case of `lea` it's actually not working with memory content, so I was not a big fan of the Intel's decision originally. Then again `lea ax,bx+si*2+permanente` looks weird too.

`MOV SI,0` - `xor si,si` - was one of first "tricks" I learned, made me understand the instructions have exact definition what they do with registers and memory, and if that effect can be used to achieve what I want, I'm free to use any of them, even if their name doesn't directly imply that usage.

Try some more different addressing modes, you don't need always to `lea` every variable address. I'm never sure what registers are allowed in 16b mode (32b protected mode allows many more combinations, so I'm used to things like [eax+ecx*8], which wouldn't work in 16b), but for example `[permanente+si]` should work ok, etc.

---

Oh, and of course get some debugger and learn how to use it. I'm pretty sure your original code must get into unexpected state in few steps inside debugger.

Also try to keep around source some "high level" comments, like for every group of 3-10 instructions. And some notes about register allocation, what value you expect where.